# Is Hardenubuntu.com legit?

Tags: 14.04, server, security

Hey all So I was looking around for methods of hardening ubuntu server and came across [hardenubuntu.com](http://hardenubuntu.com). I was wondering if you the community could tell me if the advice in this site seems legit and maybe validate it as a resource to share with others? Thanks!

Comment: I have never heard of it, it looks rubbish, not very professional, but it could be early days. Looking at some pages they give accurate code but have a high amount of disable this or that pages. I have never come across anyone who recommends disabling the compiler because hackers might compile a virus on your system ??? I would be cautious, if you disabled everything they recommend and enable the `automatic updating` they recommend (not recommended here), you potentially leave your system open to attack or broken and unstable.

Comment: I can't say for a fact if it is dodgy or not but use with caution or stay away until someone can give more information, they don't cover anything we have not covered a thousand times here. Oh and don't give it to your friends, they will hate you if they get hacked. There are many ligit sources of info on Ubuntu already, like http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ or http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/ or http://ubuntuforums.org/ PS Also note the complete lack of `contact info` or a `support` page, that's not good.